# update list box from text file at 1 second

Tags: vb6

I have a text file with the follow lines:

```
11/01/2013  00:57:59    01  00  0238    POST UNIT ID

11/01/2013  00:58:07    01  80  0136    PRE UNIT ID

11/01/2013  00:58:16    01  80  0136    PRE UNIT ID

11/01/2013  00:58:22    01  00  0238    POST UNIT ID
```

i want to read and display in a listbox text lines, but test.txt is a log file and at every second a new line is iserted in this text.With my method with timer same lines are repeating. What is the best solution to update listbox to display the latest line written in text file? I think this is a kind of update from text file...

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Timer1.Enabled = True
    Timer1.Interval = 1000

End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Timer()

    filenum = FreeFile                      
    filepath = "C:\test.txt"

    Open filepath For Input As filenum       
    Do Until EOF(filenum)                   
        Line Input #filenum, LineText       
        List1.AddItem LineText         
    Loop                                    
    Close filenum

End Sub
```

Comment: George's answer is correct, but depending on how many items are in the file your list is going to be taking a long time, possibly longer than your 1000ms poll time, to redraw the items.

Comment: I agree with jac - displaying log data in a list box is not a very good idea from design point, unless you can guarantee the file will always be small. Put in a text box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clear the list box before adding the log file

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Timer1.Enabled = True
Timer1.Interval = 1000

End Sub
Private Sub Timer1_Timer()

filenum = FreeFile                      
filepath = "C:\test.txt"

            Open filepath For Input As filenum       
            List1.Clear
            Do Until EOF(filenum)                   
                Line Input #filenum, LineText       
                List1.AddItem LineText         
            Loop                                    
            Close filenum
End Sub
```